# Excecute Excel vba code through Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, vba

Hi my question is how to execute Excel vba code through Delphi 7 program?
I found some articles in internet, which weren't described clearly.
One of them was with using OLE : 
[Article](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=442431)

I will be grateful if you can give me sample code with the answer.
Tha main problem is that I can't understant the code and I need some help.
The variable are not declared and I do not no will it work.
Thanks in advance

```
    unit Macro;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, ActnList, StdCtrls, Buttons, MSObjCtrls, ComObj, ActiveX;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        ActionList1 : TActionList;
        btnMacro : TMSBitBtn;
        acMacro : TAction;
        procedure acMacroExecute(Sender : TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1             : TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.acMacroExecute(Sender : TObject);
    var
      Excel             : OleVariant;
    begin
      Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
      Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Documents and Settings\iordan.borisov\Desktop\data.xls');
      Excel.Run('PERSONAL.XLSB!MyMacro'); // <<--- Error here.
      Excel.Quit;

    end;
    initialization
      CoInitialize(nil);
    finalization
      CoUninitialize;

    end.
```

This code throws a run time exception :

---

### Debugger Exception Notification

Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'OLE error 800A03EC'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

on line 34

Comment: The article you link to contains a reasonable answer, with code. What's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to make it work and if it work
because the code isn't very clear.

Comment: What have you tried?  The post by lespaul seems to be pretty straight forward to try.

Comment: The code is perfectly clear. What I suggest you do is attempt to write your own code based on this sample and if you get stuck, post your attempt here and include the full text of any error messages.

Comment: If I define a macro in my own local excel application with some actions and I want to run this macro throuth a delphi program how can I do it. This guy lespaul just provide some code to how to fill some cells and how to run Process_Report which I do not know is it macro or not. So how can I run my own define macro with action in Excel from Delphi program?

Comment: Removed my downvote because you provided code. Can you mark the line that's throwing the error?

Comment: What version of Excel (and in what language), what's the locale of your Delphi application, does it match the locale of Excel? The article you linked is dated 2003, lots of things changed since that day! For one macro's are disabled by default, and god knows what other changes might there be.

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty much as simple as this:

```
uses
  ComObj;
....
var
  Excel: OleVariant;
....
Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.Workbooks.Open('myworkbook.xls');
Excel.Run('MyMacro');
Excel.Quit;
```

Make sure you don't forget to call `CoInitializeEx` in order to initalize COM.

Comment: OK but it doesn't work :)

---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'OLE error 800A03EC'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Comment: It doesn't work? How about some more details.

Comment: I can't imagine why you downvoted me. The code works. Did you remember to call CoInitialize? Seriously, I wonder why I bother at times like this.

Comment: because you have mucj more experiance than me and the purpose of this web site ся to help each other :)

Comment: Yes and that's what I've been doing but the downvote that arrived at the same time as your comment doesn't encourage a sprit of helping

Comment: OK but why you down vote me each time on every question I answer?
If your code works I will checked it as an answer and upvote you :)

Comment: @JordanBorisov, I don't get your logic. David puts in effort to provide you with an answer; It doesn't immediately work for you, and when asked for details on the error you get, you slap him down with a down-vote... This site is for helping each other, that's true, but it's not for `"giving you teh codez"`. You should follow up with details, you didn't even say the line number that's giving you the error! Knowing David I wouldn't be surprised if he actually *tested* the code before posting. And if he didn't, I'm sure he did when you said it doesn't work. The problem is surely on your side.

Comment: I only paste his code compiled it with no errors but in run time cannot load the macros?

Comment: The code in this answer works.

Comment: Confirm David's answer. I've just copied that and it worked. However, if you're using Office 2010 (or maybe 2007) you might need to use .xlsm file extension and you may have to check security settings for allowing the running of macros in workbooks. But, yes, it works. You do have a macro called "MyMacro" and a workbook called "myworkbook" don't you. ;-)